# How to replace code from my chrome-extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I use the following code to disable javascript in my chrome extension:

```
   chrome.contentSettings.javascript.clear({}, function() {
        contentSettings.javascript.set({
            primaryPattern: '*://*/*',
            setting: 'block'
        });

    });
```

what a replacement for contentSettings is in FireFox?

Comment: No replacement as far as I know, Firefox doesn't offer an API for this.

Comment: Ok, but what is the most correct way to disable JavaScript programmatically in Firefox?

Comment: I don't know, try investigating. Inspect NoScript maybe.